# How to link the output of a Vector Math node to another node?

Tags: python, materials, scripting, node-editor, shaders

I try to build a operator for some specific shaders by using Python but got stuck on how to make a node connection between *ColorRamp* (input) and *Vector Math* (output):

[image]

When I try to use `shadername.links.new(VectorMath.outputs[0], ColorRamp.inputs[0])` both nodes are disconnected and I am not sure why:

[image]

Some coding excerpt:

```
 #colorRamp
    ramp = mat_ruby.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeValToRGB")
    ramp.location = (-800,100)

    ramp.color_ramp.elements[0].position=0.102
    ramp.color_ramp.elements[0].color = (0.215861,0,0.017642,1)
  
    ramp.color_ramp.elements.new(0.636)
    ramp.color_ramp.elements[1].color = (0.396755,0,0.032,1)

    ramp.color_ramp.elements.new (0.794)
    ramp.color_ramp.elements[2].color = (0.701102,0.147,0.016,1)
    
    ramp.color_ramp.elements.new(0.893)
    ramp.color_ramp.elements[3].color = (1.0,0.292,0.0,1)

    ramp.color_ramp.elements[4].position = 1
    ramp.color_ramp.elements[4].color = (1.0,1.0,1.0,1)
   
    mat_ruby.node_tree.links.new(ramp.outputs[0], glassA.inputs[0])
    

  
    math = mat_ruby.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeVectorMath')
    math.location = (-1000,100)
    math.operation = 'DOT_PRODUCT'
    mat_ruby.node_tree.links.new(math.outputs[0], ramp.inputs[0])
```

**Q:** How can I link the output of a *Vector Math* node to the input of eg. a *Color Ramp*?

Comment: Hello, I've answered your question and taken the liberty to modify the title to make it a bit more clear, feel free to revert if it doesn't feel like what you intended :)

Answer (score 2):

The [*Vector Math*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/vector_math.html) node actually has 2 outputs : One of type *Vector*, and one of type *float*. They get hidden / shown depending on the node's operation.

The *float* type is accessed with the second index of the outputs. Change your last line to :

```
mat_ruby.node_tree.links.new(math.outputs[1], ramp.inputs[0])
```

Or (**not advised** since it is language-dependant)

```
mat_ruby.node_tree.links.new(math.outputs["Value"], ramp.inputs[0])
```

Comment: That raises an interesting question.. I wonder.. can you use `locale`-translated strings to look up into this kind of dictionary?

Comment: @RobinBetts Yup that would be handy ! I never really dived into that and it's quite hard to find related docs given the keywords *locale* and *translation* :) I think it would depend if the string is translated at runtime or at compile time ? Anyway this would still be unadvisable since one could work with a material created by another person with a different locale language...